# How can I change the port in production?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I programed my Django site, and when I upload in Amazon server, the site only works in mysite.com:8000.
How can I change to work in normal mysite.com? It is a configuration in my code or in the server?

Comment: You're going to want to use something like Nginx.  There are plenty of tutorials for setting up django for production

Comment: What web server are you using?  Also, probably just a typo, but do you mean `mysite.com:8000` instead of `mysite.com/8000` ?

Comment: It sounds like you are using the development server to run your site, which you **must not do**.

Answer (score 0):

if mysite.com/8000 is a Typo mistake ,You are probably using management command to run django on production like you used to do it in development phase.
See [Django Deploy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/)

I normally use ,Chaussette and Circus with Nginx or gunicorn ,supervisor with Nginx.

If mysite.com/8000 is not a typo mistake then please edit your questions with more details about your code .

For deployment you should be aware of many things like , setting up the DEBUG = False etc

PS: make sure to allow port 80 on your security group access on AWS after you sucessfully setup deployment.